# Why wouldn't application manager run trouble script?

Tags: applicationmanager, application-monitoring

I have a job named X, and I have a condition on X as below:

[image]

But interestingly, when the condition is not met and the job is aborted, trouble script is not run. Instead I get Executing SUCCESS.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: What is "application manager"? There is no tag description and it has only been tagged on 6 questions which mostly seem to relate to android or blackberry. Please provide a link and describe how this relates to Oracle databases?

Comment: I removed oracle, you were right. http://automic.com/ is the tools that I am struggling with :)